# Can I copy files between 2 different iTunes libraries within iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music

I want to create 2 iTunes libraries on my Windows 7 PC so that my wife and I can separate our music and more easily sync to different iPods.  However, we also want to be able to share some of the music between the 2 libraries.

First question: Is the current default iTunes library folder located at \Libraries\Music\iTunes?

Question 2: If I allow iTunes to create duplicates of all the music from the original library in the new library, will I then have 2 physical copies of all music files on my hard drive?

Question 3: Based on what I have read so far, it appears that the only way to copy music from one library to another is by exporting from one library to an external location and then importing into the other directory from that external location.  Is this correct?  If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answers to your questions…

1. Yes - though that's it's 'masked' address not it's actual location.
   Real location is C:\Users\[myName]\Music\
2. Yes.
3. You can dupe the library.xml file & change the hard-coded paths to the new location, then import.
   Simple, but time-consuming.

Another downside to that method is that once you have separated the identities in such a way, they will remain forever separate & any music added to one will also need to be added to the other.
You will also have to remember to launch with the correct Library every time.

**However…**
Instead, if you use 'Sync selected playlists, artists, albums & genres you can have completely different selections for each device, even on the same ID.

I have totally different selections on my iPhone & iPod, as I use them for different things.
Might be a whole lot easier to manage.

[image]